# Выдает пустую строку при выводе функции

Tags: python, wikipedia

изучаю питон на начальном уровне. Использую библиотеку wikipedia 1.4.0 .
Мне необходимо извлечь резюме из статьи используя функцию. Но возвращается пустая строчка. Подскажите, где я ошиблась?

```
import wikipedia
wikipedia.set_lang("ru")
p = "машина"
def get_search_wiki(p):
    wiki_otvet = wikipedia.summary(p)
    return wiki_answer
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо **вызвать вашу функцию** и из нее вернуть `wiki_otvet`, а не `wiki_answer`

```
import wikipedia
wikipedia.set_lang("ru")
p = "машина"

def get_search_wiki(p): # это определение функции
    wiki_otvet = wikipedia.summary(p)
    return wiki_otvet

print(get_search_wiki(p)) # это вызов функции
```

Результат:

```
Маши́на (лат. machina — «устройство, конструкция», от др.-греч. μηχανή — «приспособление, способ») — техническое устройство, выполняющее механические движения для преобразования энергии, материалов и информации.
...
```